# Confusion with unicode in Python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, hyperlink, decode

As part of a Django site, users can enter street names and the entry will be added to a google maps geocoding link. Everything works well, until users enter special characters.

I would like to display the special character in the link, however python replaces the character with the unicode symbol. **Is there a way to prevent python from switching to unicode and simply taking the users input?** I have tried several decoders and formats, but it did not solve the problem.

edit: The code is programmed in Python 2.

I am currently requesting the JSON response as follows:

```
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
          addressString.decode('ascii') + "&sensor=false";
    googleResponse = urllib.urlopen(url);
```

Thank you for your help and advice.

Comment: you will need to specify if this is python2 or python3, since unicode handling is significantly improved in python3

Comment: Do you want Unicode characters to show in the URL as real characters (i.e. not percent-sequences)? Because that's depends on the browser, not on Python. Most modern browser should convert these sequences to Unicode, but you cannot use Unicode directly in URLs - the standard allows ASCII only.

Comment: @ninjagecko: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#can-i-use-django-with-python-3

Comment: If I cannot load urls with special characters, how can I then request French or German addresses from the google maps api. The urlopen(url) does not except the unicode, as it seems to me.

Comment: @neurix: What does `print repr(addressString)` produce?

Comment: @John Machin: The result is `Stadtstra\xc3\x9fe` which should be `Stadtstraße` ...

Comment: @neurix: [sigh] No it didn't (unless your Python is utterly broken). It printed either `'Stadtstra\xc3\x9fe'` (one hopes) or `u'Stadtstra\xc3\x9fe'` (shudder). What does `type(addressString)` produce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, check if addressString is a Unicode object (it is if you're using Python 3, or if `type(addressString)` shows 'unicode'). If it is, then you probably need to try the following:

```
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
      urllib.quote(addressString.encode('utf-8')) + "&sensor=false";
```

If addressString is a (non-unicode) string object (in Python 2) or a bytes object (in Python 3), then it must be already encoded in UTF-8. In that case, try the following:

```
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
      urllib.quote(addressString) + "&sensor=false";
```

Both of these snippets should convert the unicode characters to URL escape sequences using the `%` signs. That is the standard way of using non-ASCII characters in URL. Modern browsers should decode these sequences display these as Unicode characters.

Comment: I have tried your example - thank you for your submission - but i still get the same error message: `Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)` when requesting the link. I guess I need to look further into the problem. Thank you for your submission.

Comment: Did you try both? And did you check what kind of object addressString is? How it is encoded? We can't answer you without knowing these details.

Comment: @neurix: Also try `print repr(addressString)` as John Machin suggested.

Answer (score 2):

[big fat comment because comments can't be formatted well]

Following the instructions of @Boaz Yaniv works for me:

```
>>> addressString = 'Wilhelmstra\xc3\x9fe 123, T\xc3\xbcbingen, Deutschland'
```

That's a `str` ojbject, encoded in UTF-8. We need to percent-escape it so that it can be used in a URL.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> fixed = urllib.quote(addressString)
>>> print repr(fixed)
'Wilhelmstra%C3%9Fe%20123%2C%20T%C3%BCbingen%2C%20Deutschland'
```

Now let's try it out:

```
>>> url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + fixed +
"&sensor=false"
>>> guff = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
>>> import json
>>> print repr(json.loads(guff)['results'][0]['formatted_address'])
u'Wilhelmstra\xdfe 123, 72074 T\xfcbingen, Germany'
>>>
```

If you have something like this: `'Wilhelmstra\xdfe 123, T\xfcbingen, Deutschland'`, that's a `str` object encoded in latin1 or cp1252 or whatever. You'll need to decode that to a `unicode` object then encode that in UTF-8 then percent-escape it.

However if you have (VERY subtle difference) `u'Wilhelmstra\xdfe 123, T\xfcbingen, Deutschland'`, that's a `unicode` object and you'll need to encode that in UTF-8 then percent-escape it.

You said """
i still get the same error message: Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdf' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128) when requesting the link
"""

This looks like you are feeding a `unicode` object to something which wants a `str` object and tries to get it by encoding using the (usual default) `ascii` encoding. If you continue to have this problem, show your code. Break it down to the minimum necessary (as I did above). Show repr(step_by_step_results).

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure, try:

url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" +
        addressString.decode('utf-8') + "&sensor=false";
googleResponse = urllib.urlopen(url);

Comment: urllib.urlopen() does not take unicode. You need to encode it in UTF-8 and then percent-escape it -- see the answer by @Boaz Yaniv.